# Handling the salary expectation question

Tags: interviewing, salary

How would you answer to a question "what are your salary expectations/do you have a salary expectation?" if you don't want to give a number, but you want them to make the first offer? How could I handle that? Because they ask a straight question and they expect a number.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by giving a range, and qualify it if you think it will help. "I am expecting a salary in the $60,000 to $70,000 range given my years of experience doing X, and the level of responsibility and the amount of travel involved in this role."  Do your homework first to figure out what your industry is paying for this type of work.

Comment: Range is common advice, but I don't get it.  Why put an upper bound on it? Are you really going to turn down a $80K offer b/c it is out of range.  Your real range is $60K<->infinity - which is the same as giving $60K as a number.

Comment: @emory Agree.  I get the company would have range for a position for someone that is highly qualified versus barely qualified but as a person you just have a minimum.

Comment: I just say market rate for the location and leave it at that

Answer (score 0):

Answer by giving them a high number.

1. If they discontinue communication then maybe your number is too high (but who really knows why they do the things they do).
2. If they make a lower counter offer, then how is this any different from them making the first offer.  (Assuming your high number really was high.)
3. If they accept your high offer without trying a counter offer, then your high number was not high enough.